# How do you create new column from two distinct categorical column values in a dataframe by same column ID in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry for the confusing title. I am practicing how to manipulate dataframes in Python through pandas. How do I make this kind of table:

```
    id   role                      name
0   11  ACTOR       Luna Wedler, Jannis Niewöhner, Milan Peschel, ...
1   11  DIRECTOR    Christian Schwochow
2   22  ACTOR       Guy Pearce, Matilda Anna Ingrid Lutz, Travis F...
3   22  DIRECTOR    Andrew Baird
4   33  ACTOR       Glenn Fredly, Marcello Tahitoe, Andien Aisyah,...
5   33  DIRECTOR    Saron Sakina
```

Into this kind:

```
    id  director                       actors name                            
0   11  Christian Schwochow   Luna Wedler, Jannis Niewöhner, Milan Peschel, ...
1   22  Andrew Baird          Guy Pearce, Matilda Anna Ingrid Lutz, Travis F...d
2   33  Saron Sakina          Glenn Fredly, Marcello Tahitoe, Andien Aisyah,...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
df.pivot(index='id', columns='role', values='name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in addition to @Tejas's answer:

```
df = (df.pivot(index='id', columns='role', values='name').
       reset_index().
       rename_axis('',axis=1).
       rename(columns={'ACTOR':'actors name','DIRECTOR':'director'}))
```